# 20A current measurement with hall effect sensor

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, heat, high-current, high-power

I am not aware of drawing more than 1A over PCB traces. We are planning to use ACS712 hall effect current sensor linked below:

https://www.amazon.in/KitsGuru-KG134-ACs712-Current-Arduino/dp/B00YY3UK6S

Can anyone help with the width and depth of the traces for such higher currents?

How far should I place other components including microcontroller?

Should I have heat sink or such arrangements?

Or should I solder copper wire with 5mm thickness to connectors and place sensor module above it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Copper track thickness calculators are available on the internet.

Comment: Hello @Andyaka thanks for the reply. I've seen one of the calculator over here. http://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html

Comment: That uses ipc-2221 which is opsolete for amperage. Find one that uses ipc-2152